# moving back ground using single image in cocos2dx v3

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0

I am new in cocos2dx programming.Please can  anybody help me about moving background sprite by using single image  with code but the code should be in cocos2dx-3.0 because i have already search this problem but all code is in old cocos2dx thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**I get this example for a cocos2d-x Book**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
{
    backgroundSpriteArray[i] = Sprite::create
    ("GameScreen/Game_Screen_Background.png");
    backgroundSpriteArray[i]->setPosition
    (Point((visibleSize.width / 2) + origin.x, (-1 *
    visibleSize.height * i) + (visibleSize.height / 2) +
    origin.y));
    this->addChild(backgroundSpriteArray[i], -2);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
{
    backgroundSpriteArray[i]->setPosition
    (Point(backgroundSpriteArray[i]->getPosition().x,
    backgroundSpriteArray[i]->getPosition().y + (0.75 *
    visibleSize.height * dt)));
}
```

**Although the backgrounds scroll, they do not reset once they have gone
above the screen. Add the following code above the previous code:**

```
Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->
getVisibleSize();
Point origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
{
if (backgroundSpriteArray[i]->getPosition().y >=
visibleSize.height + (visibleSize.height / 2) -1)
{
    backgroundSpriteArray[i]->setPosition
    (Point((visibleSize.width / 2) + origin.x, (-1 *
    visibleSize.height) + (visibleSize.height / 2)));
}
}
```